# Express GET route will not work with parameters or additionnal path

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch, router

I can't make a fetch request when i try to add additional path or params...

THis is what I want to :

```
const fetchOwnerCardList = () => {
  fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/card/ownerCards", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
    },
  })
    .then((reponse) => reponse.json())
    .then((allSpikemmon) => {
      console.log(allSpikemmon);.................................
.............
.............
```

If a do exactly the same using
`fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/card/")` it works perfectly...

I am really confused.
Here is my route file :

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router(); //création d'un routeur express dans lequel on va enregistrer nos routes

//Importation controllers
const stuffCtrl = require("../controllers/card");
const auth = require("../middleware/auth"); //auth
const multer = require("../middleware/multer"); //gestions des images
//Routes

router.post("/", auth, multer, stuffCtrl.createCard); //Création de card
router.get("/:name", stuffCtrl.getOneCard); //recup une card

router.get("/ownerCards", auth, stuffCtrl.getOwnCards);

module.exports = router; //exportations de notre routeur
```

and in my server.js file I have this line `app.use("/api/card", CardsRoutes);`

SO the problem come from the client server side but i can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`router.get("/:name")` will match `/ownerCards` which is a problem.  Put the `/ownerCards` route first like this:

```
router.post("/", auth, multer, stuffCtrl.createCard); //Création de card

router.get("/ownerCards", auth, stuffCtrl.getOwnCards);
router.get("/:name", stuffCtrl.getOneCard); //recup une card
```

Remember that `/:name` matches anything at that path level.  I call it a wildcard route so if you have any other routes at that level, then you need to make sure they are before the greedy wildcard route definition.